# App transfer from one apple account to other got issues

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, app-transfer

I have transferred my app from one apple store to another apple store account. The transfer has been successfull but the subscribed users are facing issues now. They are being asked to re-subscribe to the app. I want them to remain subscribed.

Is there any way to overcome this problem like re-transfer the app to the old account or is there any other solution?